# How to map(concatenate) labels of two metrics

Tags: prometheus, promql

I have two metrics :

```
 m1: ifAdminStatus{ifDescr="GigabitEthernet0/25",instance="192.168.1.1",job="snmp"}  0
```

and

```
m2: ifAlias{ifAlias="Link 2",ifDescr="GigabitEthernet0/25",instance="192.168.1.1",job="snmp"} 1
```

I need map/group this metrics on ifDescr label and result must have all labels from m1 and m2 and value m1.value*m2.value.
Result:

```
 {ifAlias="Link 2",i-fDescr="GigabitEthernet0/25",instance="192.168.1.1",job="snmp"} 0
```

i try

```
ifAlias{ifAlias="Link 2",ifDescr="GigabitEthernet0/25",instance="192.168.1.1",job="snmp"} * on (ifAlias) group_left(ifDescr) ifAdminStatus{ifDescr="GigabitEthernet0/25",instance="192.168.1.1",job="snmp"}
```

but result is empty( pls. help me )

Answer (score 0):

Solved!! Figured it might come in handy.

```
m1 * on (ifDescr) group_left(ifAlias) m2
```

or

```
 ifAdminStatus{ifDescr="GigabitEthernet0/25",instance="192.168.1.1",job="snmp"} * on (ifDescr) group_left(ifAlias) ifAlias{ifAlias="Link 2",ifDescr="GigabitEthernet0/25",instance="192.168.1.1",job="snmp"}
```